# Plot Survival by Kaplan-Meier and Fleming on same plot in R

Tags: r, survival

I need simple help on how to plot kaplan-Meier and Fleming-Harrington Survival estimators on same plot. I have tried several efforts with ggplot2 to no avail. A kind help by anyone would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider editing your question so it is suitable to migrate to stackoverflow. That means including a reproducible example along with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(survminer) library(survival)

#### Kaplan-Meier 
kaplan_meier <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1, 
  data = dataset, type = "kaplan-meier")

#### Flemming-Harrington 
fleming_harrington  <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1,
  data = dataset, type = "fleming-harrington")

### Add both survfits to the list 
fits <- list(kaplan_meier = kaplan_meier, 
  fleming_harrington = fleming_harrington)

ggsurvplot(fits, thoracic, combine = TRUE, palette = "jco", conf.int = TRUE, 
  conf.int.style = "step")
```

Comment: Yeah that's quite helpful...